# python geometric sequence

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a problem in my book but I have no idea how.  The question is, Write function geometric() that takes a list of integers as input and returns True if the integers in the list form a geometric sequence. A sequence a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,...,an-2,an-1 is a geometric sequence if the ratios a1/a0,a2/a1,a3/a2,a4/a3,...,an-1/an-2 are all equal.

```
def geometric(l):
for i in l:
    if i*1==i*0:
        return True
else:
    return False
```

I honestly have no idea how to start this and I'm completely drawing a blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

For example:

```
geometric([2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256])
>>> True

geometric([2,4,6,8])`
>>> False
```

Answer (score 3):

This should efficiently handle all iterable objects.

```
from itertools import izip, islice, tee

def geometric(obj):
    obj1, obj2 = tee(obj)
    it1, it2 = tee(float(x) / y for x, y in izip(obj1, islice(obj2, 1, None)))
    return all(x == y for x, y in izip(it1, islice(it2, 1, None)))

assert geometric([2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256])
assert not geometric([2,4,6,8])
```

Check out itertools - http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: But you loose shortcircuiting in the `all()` right? You've had to calculate all the ratios.

Comment: Nope, `all` should take care of short-circuiting.  Try out `geometric(xrange(1,1000000000))` ... runs in no time.

Comment: Thanks!  Note - added in `tee` to prevent iteration clashing in the `izip(it1, islice(it2, 1, None))` section.

Comment: Interesting. Would you not have to do that for `obj` as well?

Answer (score 1):

One easy method would be like this:

```
def is_geometric(a):
    r = a[1]/float(a[0])
    return all(a[i]/float(a[i-1]) == r for i in xrange(2,len(a)))
```

Basically, it calculates the ratio between the first two, and uses `all` to determine if all members of the generator are true.  Each member of the generator is a boolean value representing whether the ratio between two numbers is equal to the ratio between the first two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. It's essentially the same as pyrospade's itertools code, but with the generators disassembled. As a bonus, I can stick to purely integer math by avoid doing any division (which might, in theory, lead to floating point rounding issues):

```
def geometric(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        a = next(it)
        b = next(it)
        if a == 0 or b == 0:
            return False
        c = next(it)
        while True:
            if a*c != b*b: # <=> a/b != b/c, but uses only int values
                return False
            a, b, c = b, c, next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
```

Some test results:

```
>>> geometric([2,4,8,16,32])
True
>>> geometric([2,4,6,8,10])
False
>>> geometric([3,6,12,24])
True
>>> geometric(range(1, 1000000000)) # only iterates up to 3 before exiting
False
>>> geometric(1000**n for n in range(1000)) # very big numbers are supported
True
>>> geometric([0,0,0]) # this one will probably break every other code
False
```

Comment: You should note that this is Python 3 code (since in Python 2.x `range` does not return an iterator).  This is a really great solution.  Genius idea to algebraically rearrange `a/b != b/c` to `a*c != b*b`.  I am jealous!

Comment: The only problem is that `geometric([0,0,0])` probably should not be `True` since geometric sequences are defined using division - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: @pyrospade: Regarding [0,0,0], you may be right. It depends a bit on how you define things. The Wikipedia page on [Geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) gives a definition that an all-zero sequence meets (`0, 0*r, 0*r**2, ...` for any `r`), but the question does have a definition that requires division. In any case, my algebraic manipulation of the ratios is not allowed if `b` or `c` is zero, so I suppose it's calculating incorrectly anyway.

Comment: May be a good question for math.stackexchange.  Either way, excellent solution.  Easy enough to add in a check for zero and return `False` or throw an error.

Comment: @pyrospade: good idea. I've added a check for `a` or `b` being zero at the start, and any zero that comes later will make the inequality false.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
def is_geometric(l):
    if len(l) <= 1: # Edge case for small lists
        return True
    ratio = l[1]/float(l[0]) # Calculate ratio
    for i in range(1, len(l)): # Check that all remaining have the same ratio
        if l[i]/float(l[i-1]) != ratio: # Return False if not
            return False
    return True # Return True if all did
```

And for the more adventurous

```
def is_geometric(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return True
    r = l[1]/float(l[0])
    # Check if all the following ratios for each
    # element divided the previous are equal to r
    # Note that i is 0 to n-1 while e is l[1] to l[n-1]
    return all(True if e/float(l[i]) == r else False for (i, e) in enumerate(l[1:]))
```